# PostgreSQL: using strings in SQL subquery text in a function

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I'm using the [pgr_drivingDistance](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgr_drivingDistance.html) function that requires a SQL subquery as text like so:

```
pgr_drivingDistance(
'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edges', start_vid, dist, true
)
```

I would like to subset the edges in the edges table with a where clause like so:

```
pgr_drivingDistance(
'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edges WHERE col = 'some_string'', start_vid, dist, true
)
```

The problem is I cannot use single quotes in this case for the string. I tried to escape the quotes of the string with ''', backslash, $$ notations without success.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can escape single quote by doubling them, so, make it like `...WHERE col = ''some_str'' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various ways to escape single quotes (apostrophes) in [Postgres string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

- "*To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes*"

  ```
  pgr_drivingDistance('SELECT … WHERE col = ''some_string'' ', start_vid, dist, true)
  ```
- "*A single quote can be included in an escape string by writing `\'`, in addition to the normal way of `''`.*"

  ```
  pgr_drivingDistance(e'SELECT … WHERE col = \'some_string\' ', start_vid, dist, true)
  ```
- "*Inside the dollar-quoted string, single quotes can be used without needing to be escaped*"

  ```
  pgr_drivingDistance($$SELECT … WHERE col = 'some_string'$$, start_vid, dist, true)
  ```